# Extracting head tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try lots of things but I couldn't extract content of `head`. Any one help?

**Original XML:** https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3482709/English_sense_induction.xml.zip

Here is the text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE corpus SYSTEM "sense-induction.dtd">
<corpus lang="en">
  <lexelt item="explain.v">
    <instance id="explain.v.4" corpus="wsj">
For OPEC , that 's ideal . The resulting firm prices and stability `` will allow both producers and consumers to plan confidently , '' says Saudi Arabian Oil Minister Hisham Nazer . OPEC Secretary-General Subroto <head> explains </head> : Consumers offer security of markets , while OPEC provides security of supply . `` This is an opportune time to find mutual ways { to prevent } price shocks from happening again , '' he says . To promote this balance , OPEC now is finally confronting a long-simmering internal problem .
</instance>
    <instance id="explain.v.10" corpus="wsj">
and given the right conditions , sympathetic to creating some form of life . Surely at some other cosmic address a Gouldoid creature would have risen out of the ooze to <head> explain </head> why , paleontologically speaking , `` it is , indeed , a wonderful life . '' Mr. Holt is a columnist for the Literary Review in London .
</instance>
    <instance id="explain.v.76" corpus="wsj">
`` You ca n't build on your hit-and-miss five-seventeen '' . `` What are you playing '' ? ? Owen asked . `` I 'm just logging '' , the cowboy <head> explained </head> . `` I keep all these plays in this little black book , and I watch over a twelve-hour period to find out what numbers are repeating . But roulette 's not my game .
</instance>
  </lexelt>
  <lexelt item="position.n">
    <instance id="position.n.288" corpus="wsj">
But not everybody was making money . The carnage on the Chicago Board Options Exchange , the nation 's major options market , was heavy after the trading in S&amp;P 100 stock-index options was halted Friday . Many market makers in the S&amp;P 100 index options contract had bullish <head> positions </head> Friday , 
</instance>
    <instance id="position.n.123" corpus="wsj">
An explosion at the Microbiology and Virology Institute in Sverdlovsk released anthrax germs that caused a significant number of deaths . Since Mr. Shevardnadze did not address this topic before the Supreme Soviet , the Soviet Union 's official <head> position </head> remains that the anthrax deaths were caused by 
</instance>
  </lexelt>
</corpus>
```

**EDIT**

Problem was that I forgot `xml` as second argument: Solution is `soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_data, 'xml')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_data, 'xml')
head_datas = [head.get_text() for head in soup.find_all('head')]

head_datas
>>> [' explains ', ' explain ', ' explained ', ' positions ', ' position ']
```

You can also use the `.string` attribute if `<head>` contains only one child which is a string:

```
head_datas = [head.string for head in soup.find_all('head')]
```

Comment: You can add more value to this answer with some short explanation of what's going on, to help the original poster and future readers understand.

Comment: Perhaps the links to the documentation: [`.get_text()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text), [`.string`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string)

Comment: Does not work. could you try it again on newer version of xml.

Comment: It works with the data you gave in your question, just change the value of `xml_data`...

Comment: I am surprised. I am trying again. what is xml_data? String or file descriptor?

Comment: `xml_data` can be a string or something like `open('yourfile.xml')`. I've just tried the both cases (with your original file) and it works.

Comment: I don't get it. I tried again but empty list again. What is your Python version?

Comment: Guys, problem solved. Magic is `soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'xml')`.. AARRRGG!

Comment: Cool :) Sorry, I didn't think about this argument as it strangely worked without it on my computer

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> t = '''<?xml ...'''
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(t)
>>> soup.find('head')
<head> explains </head>
>>> _.text
' explains '
```

As you are using a valid XML structure, you could also use a different XML parser, like ElementTree:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> tree = ElementTree.fromstring(t)
>>> tree.find('.//head')
<Element 'head' at 0x00000000031226D8>
>>> _.text
' explains '
```

Comment: It does not work for me. Maybe I add more parts of my xml file.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you get an error? What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I change the xml a bit. Could you please try again? Python 2.7, bs4 4.1.3

Comment: I can’t test it with BeatifulSoup on Python 2.7 as I don’t have it installed on this machine, but at least the ElementTree example works in Python 2.7 and your changed XML. I’m using bs4.1.3 in Python 3 too and I don’t expect that to be different to the Python 2 version, so that should work too. Btw. in case you want to find all `head` elements (and not just the first), use BeatifulSoup’s `soup.findAll('head')` or ElementTree’s `tree.findall('.//head')` isntead.

Comment: @Thorn: Are you using beautifulsoup 4?

Comment: Yeah Nicolas. In [2]: bs4.__version__ = 4.1.3'

Comment: Guys, problem solved. Magic is `soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'xml')`.. AARRRGG!